# How can I make the normals of both sides of my mesh pointing outwards?

Tags: mesh, faces

[image: Face Orientation Flip]

Anyone have any tips to help me. I want both sides to be blue but I don't know an easy and fast way to do it I am wondering if anyone know a great way to fix this and make both the inside and outside blue.

Comment: Hello, Edgar ... please clarify this question. Do you just want to change the colours of the face-orientation overlay? Or make all your faces front-facing? And please give us your reason for wanting this, too, just in case there's a better way to your objective.

Comment: The simple answer is: you cannot. A face will always have a front- and backside, and the normal will always only point in one direction. Everything else is a workaround with additional faces. See the answer given here and the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give thickness to your walls, you can try to do it with the *Solidify* modifier, but I'm afraid it may give bad topology with your mesh. Actually you need to anticipate the problem when you begin to model your object.

[image]

As pointed out by Gorgious, if you plan to use your object in a game engine, you can set the *Solidify* to 0, it won't create any artefact in your game engine and a face will be seen on both side.

Comment: I think if you set the solidify thickness to 0 it answers the question without creating artifacts. I guess they want this model to be rendered in another engine, possibly a game engine which has Backface Culling ON by default. Note it will double the geometry count though. You may have better luck disabling backface culling altogether

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the Solidify at 0, it seems to create overlapping faces. I know that it creates more topology but does he have the choice?

Comment: Indeed the faces do overlap when you have Backface culling turned off, however if you turn it on, the renderer only sees one set of faces in either direction and there is no Z-fighting. I was just pointing it out in case OP wonders about it, I think your solution answer the question. Cheers

Comment: Oh ok i didn't know this solution, interesting